# practicing lldb python programming without xcode or mac

Tags: python, windows, lldb

I would like to practice debugging in lldb, especially how to use python scripts with lldb for viewing contents of variables of a C program, but I don't have access to Xcode or an Apple computer. Is it still possible to run lldb and practice it's python scripting? Searching for lldb download takes me [here](https://lldb.llvm.org/download.html) and it doesn't look like there is a windows installer available.

Am I going about this the right way, or is it impossible to practice lldb and it's python scripting without an Apple computer?

The target computer is Windows 7 32 bit.

Answer (score 0):

I develop on Mac but found this post on the LLVM website, perhaps it may be useful to you.
http://blog.llvm.org/2015/01/lldb-is-coming-to-windows.html

edit: researching more, it's (maybe) still under development...
https://lldb.llvm.org/status.html (the first post is almost 4 years old)

Comment: Hi thanks for the answer. If you don't mind could you please have a look at my other question as well, in case you have some ideas on it?

Comment: Python on windows gives me a headache.  I have never used LLVM on windows at all, so I really can't guess as to the difficulty.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to link my other question. This is the other question I was talking about: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53331618/lldb-python-basic-print-value-of-a-global-array-while-inside-a-breakpoint-in-a . It's actually not about windows. It's about the python scripting in lldb in xcode on mac. I need to find out how to display an array's elements, without any formatting (formatting such as the array indices displayed by default by the expression command)

Comment: I figured it was a more general question and is probably easy for someone who as experience with python on lldb

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you run a Linux VM which makes it easy to work with LLVM in general and lldb in particular.

Comment: I was hoping if there was a way to do it without using VM's.

Comment: If you haven’t found a way, it might be time thinking about your constraints and which you can relax. Using a VM is easy, and free. And makes no discernible difference as in both environments you won’t get Xcode like GUI integration.