# Using matplotlib in iphone lldb (obj-c)

Tags: ios, xcode, python-2.7, matplotlib, lldb

I am trying to find a way to display the values in arrays in my ojective-C based iphone program, as [described in my other question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53331618/lldb-python-basic-print-value-of-a-global-array-while-inside-a-breakpoint-in-a)

I am able to get the contents of an array in my program into the python interpreter while the iphone program is stopped at a break point inside a function (to be specific, the function is the render callback function for audio)

However, when I tried to plot the contents of the array (availabe as SBValueList in the Python interpreter) using matplotlib, the debug session simply crashed without any error messages

To try a simple example, once the program stopped at the breakpoint, I tried issuing a very simple matplotlib command as follows:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.plot([1,2,3,4])
```

but the debug session suddenly crashes and exits at `plt.plot([1,2,3,4])`

Is it possible to display contents of array in lldb using matplotlib? Is there any other way to display the contents of my array a graph while debugging my iphone program?

Answer (score 0):

I'd consider taking a step back. If you can render your `objective-c` array as a plot on `UIView` or `UIImage` you could view it while standing on a breakpoint with `chisel`:
https://github.com/facebook/chisel 
[image]